# The entity or complex type 'EmployeeStoreModel.karthiktable' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

```
   public List<class> method( )
            {
            return _context.OffshoreTransactions.Select ( x => new OffshoreTransactionRecord
            {
                CheckNumber = x.CheckNumber,
                Comment = x.Comment,
                Description = x.Description,
                TransactionAmount = x.Amount,
                TransactionId = x.TransactionTypeId,
                Upload = x.UploadFile,
                Id = x.Id

            } ).ToList ();
            }
```

The entity or complex type 'XXX' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: I am able to get the records in my context here in the above problem

Answer (score 1):

```
 using ( context)
            {
                // Get all constructed type product and then select from it
                var subcate = context.karthiktables
                 .ToList()
                 .Select(x => new karthiktable
                 {
                     name = x.name,
                     F_name = x.F_name,
                     L_name = x.L_name,
                     Address = x.Address,
                     T_Address = x.T_Address,
                     Id = x.Id
                 });

                return subcate;
```

Comment: Thank You I got It But what is the difference Between Two I got the result from your post